# ArcGIS adding extra columns to CSV - can I delete them?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have a data file with a few million entries. For geocoding, I split this into 12 files, just to make the file size a bit more manageable / easier to trouble shoot issues like the one I'm having now.

In each of these files, I have the following columns/information: ReportToken, address, city, st, zip, addr1, addr2, full address; where ReportToken is a person-specific identifier, addr1 and addr2 are the street address with the apartment units split into addr2. Address is the entire street address including the apartment/unit number if applicable, and full address is address, city, st, zip.

In 1 of these 12 files, ArcGIS is adding two columns: addr2_X and addr2_Y, right after the addr2 column. I guess ArcGIS thinks these have lat and long values. Most of addr2 are  values, but, sprinkled through each of the 12 files, there are some units/apartments in the addr2 column.

The addr2_X and addr2_Y only have values if addr2 has information, but they do not have information for every line where addr2 has data. It only appears where addr2 has "APT " followed by a number that is an even number of digits (e.g. addr2 with "APT 16" has addr2_X/Y values, the addr2 with "APT 116" does not). Again, in the other 11 files, there are addr2 values that have apt numbers with even numbers of digits, and this extra column thing isn't occuring. I have no idea where ArcGIS thinks it's getting this lat/long info: the files themselves just have text and are not spatial files.

I cannot share this data, and I have been unable to replicate the problem with dummy data. I am using this CSV file to geocode the addresses, but am not geocoding on the Addr2 column (I am geocoding on the address column). Can I delete the addr2_X/Y columns, or should I be more concerned about why this is popping up?

Comment: Sorry - I just didn't know what might be causing the problem, I can't post my data, and I can't reproduce it using dummy data. But: just add data, where I load the csv and boom there the two bonus columns are

Comment: Are the data in `addr2` altered in any way in the imported CSV or are they what you expect to see? Incidentally, for such a large dataset, instead of splitting into multiple files I would consider using a database, it will be much more manageable.